# Disable click on datalabel in pie

Tags: highcharts

How do I disable click on a datalabel in a PIE?

In previous version 2.3.2 click on a datalabel doesn't have any action on the pie. How do I get that in version 3.0.4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no strict way to get that behavior back, probably there were requests from users to make this work that way. However, you can disable this by overwriting 'click' event on dataLabels:

```
    chart: {
        events: {
            load: function () {
                var chart = this,
                    points = chart.series[0].data,
                    pLen = points.length;

                for (var i = 0; i < pLen; i++) {
                    points[i].dataLabel.on('click', function (e) {
                        e.stopPropagation();
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    },
```

Working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fusher/NPxNS/4/).

Answer (score 0):

```
legendItemClick: function() {
    return false;
```

}

Comment: this doesn't work http://jsfiddle.net/NPxNS/1/  Also on documentation "Not applicable to pies, as the legend item is per point. See point.events."

Comment: yes.. but you should use it like : http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/pie-point-events-legenditemclick/

Answer (score 0):

set useHTML to false

```
$("#container").highcharts({
    legend: {
        useHTML: false
    }
});
```

Comment: this doesn't work. http://jsfiddle.net/NPxNS/  Now try click on any datalabel you will see that the selected pie item changes

Comment: I thought you were using the legend, you didn't specify in OP.